# Odd behavior of 2^0 for fixed point Matlab

Tags: matlab, fixed-point

I'm trying to implement the equivalent of C data types, e.g., `int32_t`, with MATLAB. As far as I know (suggestions welcome!), the right way to do this is to define my own `my_int32` like so:

```
function y = my_int32(x)
%MY_UINT16 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

persistent T32 F32
T32 = numerictype('Signedness', 'Signed', ...
'WordLength', 32, ...
'FractionLength', 0);
F32 = fimath('RoundingMethod', 'Zero', ...
'OverflowAction', 'Wrap', ...
'ProductMode', 'KeepLSB', ...
'ProductWordLength', 32, ...
'ProductFractionLength', 0, ...
'SumMode', 'KeepLSB', ...
'SumWordLength', 32, ...
'SumFractionLength', 0, ...
'CastBeforeSum', true);

y = fi(x, T32, F32);
end
```

Now I get some odd behavior for 2^0:

```
>> my_int32(2)^1

ans = 

     2

          DataTypeMode: Fixed-point: binary point scaling
            Signedness: Signed
            WordLength: 32
        FractionLength: 0

        RoundingMethod: Zero
        OverflowAction: Wrap
           ProductMode: KeepLSB
     ProductWordLength: 32
               SumMode: KeepLSB
         SumWordLength: 32
         CastBeforeSum: true
>> my_int32(2)^0

ans = 

     1

          DataTypeMode: Fixed-point: binary point scaling
            Signedness: Unsigned
            WordLength: 1
        FractionLength: 0

        RoundingMethod: Zero
        OverflowAction: Wrap
           ProductMode: KeepLSB
     ProductWordLength: 32
               SumMode: KeepLSB
         SumWordLength: 32
         CastBeforeSum: true
```

For some reason, the word length of `my_int32(2)^0` is not 32, but 1. I've tried things like `my_int32(2)^my_int32(0)` to no avail. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: This could be caused by how computations are performed with this system. Why not just use the `int32` type?

Comment: Arithmetic with MATLAB's `int32` and C's `int32_t` doesn't match up. As an easier example, when working with `uint8`'s, in MATLAB, `0 - 1 = 0` but in C `0 - 1 = 255`. I want the C version of wrap around overflow.

Comment: How about `my_int32(2)^0 + my_int32(0)` ?  That won't change the value but might (?) change the type back to what's required?

Comment: @BenVoigt, that worked!